# Replicating an upload field also copies the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery function :

```
makeupload = function() {
    if (filecount == 7) {
        alert('You can Only upload up to 10 files');
    } else {
        filecount++;
        var el = $('div#fileupload');
        el = el[el.length - 1];
        el = $(el);
        var nel = el.clone();
        nel.val('');
        var fi = nel.find("#fileinput");
        fi.attr("name", "file[]");
        fi.val('');
        el.after(nel);
        nel.show();
        fi.bind("change", function(e) {
            makeupload();
        });
    }
}
makeupload();
```

in firefox only it replicates the value of the last field, so if I browse an image and then add a new field using the function above, it replicates the value inside the field for the new one.

here is the html file :

```
<div id="fileupload" style=""><input type="file" name="file[]" /><br /></div>
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code next time (I've done it for you this time). It's not only for us who seek to help you, it's for your own sake to be able to read your own code.

Comment: It seems like your cloning method will create duplicate element-IDs. I am not sure if this is the root cause of the above-mentioned problem but it is a bad practice in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know what the current state of your code is (the code above can’t work as it is at least), so I took the liberty to refactor your function. I also removed the ID attribute from the mark–up and replaced it with a class attribute, since you really shouldn't be cloning IDs.

The following version seems to [**work just fine**](http://jsfiddle.net/uc2KN/1/) in FF:

```
var max_upload = 10;

var make_upload = function() {
    var $uploads = $(".fileupload");

    if ($uploads.length >= max_upload) {
        alert("You can only upload up to 10 files");

    } else {
        var $last = $uploads.last();

        $last
            .clone()
            .insertAfter($last)
            .find("input")
            .val("")
            .bind("change", function() {
                make_upload();
            });
    }
}

make_upload();
```